# Tridion 2011 How to create workflow with multiple components inside

Tags: 2011, workflow

I need to create a workflow and associated to it some components. Once the workflow is started, these components will be sent to a web service for a traduction and I need to block them through this workflow. Does anyone knows how to do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Bundle (multi-item) workflow was introduced in 2013. In 2011 you'll need to build your own solution for something like this.

Comment: Ok Nuno thanks for the answer. So I guess i will need to create a method to check-out the components until the traducion procress finish and after the process translate the content and update the component do a check-in.

Comment: I know some people did similar things, maybe someone feels like sharing?

Answer (score 3):

As the others have said in SDL Tridion 2011 you can't manage multiple items in workflow as a single 'unit'.

Perhaps you could consider some twist on use of Bundles (if you can't get your client to upgrade to a more recent and more feature packed version of the CMS):

- use a virtual folder to hold the components you require through this workflow instance (perhaps referenced via a naming convention or even better some sort of 'translation' metadata field title {translation-project, "xyz"}
- when you start workflow on any item within the virtual folder you would then (obviously - through the API) start workflow on the other components contained within the virtual folder

  - perhaps then update the metadata on the virtual folder to indicate 'in-translation' or 'in-workflow'
  - thinking loudly here - you could have a specific 'translation user' that you assign these in-workflow items to - it would help filtering etc. and you'd have an out of the box method of checking what items are currently checked out to translation (i.e. the checked-out page, sorted by checked-out to :) )
- as any item within the virtual folder is progressed to the next activity the first check is areThereOtherItemsInMyReleaseVirtualFolder(comp) and then progress these too

This is a super-simplistic view and may support a real simple release/editorial process - so it depends on your overall scope/business requirements.

The more you look into this, the more you will appreciate the complexity that is required to support bundle management (and just one of the benefits of upgrading), for example

- need to manage not having items in multiple virtual folders that would attempt to add a component to multiple active workflow instances
- need to manage who can edit items, check them out in workflow etc - as these are no-longer 'single' items but a collective
- and a heck of a lot more (including the checks you'll need on the above suggested steps)

You could have a chunk of metadata on the virtual folder to manage who can edit/update/progress the workflow - with workflow reading this (and the event system also to stop editing of content in these folders whilst in the translation phase for example).

This would be an interesting project but as much of the work has already been done - consider the upgrade and get Bundling!

Answer (score 0):

To start a Workflow from the UI with multiple items, you must use a Bundle Workflow as mentioned above.

If you want to use a "normal" Workflow, on Component or Page change, you can add additional items to the Workflow subjects via the API, but not via the UI.

Update based on Nuno's comment. The above is true for 2013 SP1

Comment: In 2011? You can't add multiple subjects to a 2011 workflow.

Comment: Whoops! Missed the 2011 part